# ERROR!!! Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I ran into an error and I have not figured out how to resolve it alone. so I opted to get help from this community. I will explain a bit though the screenshots are provided.

I created a new laravel project, created a database, users table, connected the env file with the required info, created a factory, seeders with the artisan make: command

when I tried generating the fakers with the help of factory and seeders for my student table, after running the command "PHP artisan DB:seed" -> I got the error msg

Any help will be appreciated

[Env File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRfld.png%5C)

[Student_Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s39cr.png)

[Student_Factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc2xC.png)

[Student_factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcX1v.png)

[Error_msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7tSA.png)

[Link Based on error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRQ0L.png)

[Link based on error msg 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVHQs.png)

[Link based on error msg 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ8BZ.png)

[Link based on error msg 4][9]

[Database_seeder file][10]

Comment: Hey mate, with stack overflow its generally frowned apon to link to images as stack overflow has no control over the hosting of those images and in future if this question is to help someone and the images 404. please write your code in backticks `e.g. like this`

Comment: Did you migrate your database before seeding? The error is saying the table students does not exist in the database.

Comment: also change the students table `$table->id()` to `$table->bigIncrements('id');`

Comment: @ IGP yes, I did, The Student table consists of just the columns and no data yet. I intend to use the faker option to data fake users. I migrated before seeding, I also dropped the table and from my MySQL workbench, I could see the table active and up. I also verified the migration status using the artisan migration:status and every thing looks fine.

Comment: @MichaelMano Yes, I am new here. I will do what you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the name of *student table* is different in your migration file, you should use **students** so Laravel could find the table, if you want to keep your table name **student**, you should specify that in your model **Student**.

Answer (score 0):

I found in you migration file, the table name was `student`, not `students`.
Change the `student` to `students` in your migration file and try again.

Often, we use plural words as table names, like `students`, `users`, `admins`, `products`.